# adding one column text file to two column text file using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am very much new to MATLAB.

I have two text file. One has two columns `xy.txt` (X AND Y coordinates). It has 80640 points.

The second has one column `z.txt` (z value according to the coordinate). The second text file is  a result of a matlab program that I wrote. That program produces the z value for every 10 year time interval. I am modelling impact of sea-level rise during this century.

I want to make three column text file to  plot contour maps.

I want to include that code to the main script I wrote so that I can get the contour map automatically.

I searched almost a day to find suitable answer but in vain

Thank you

Comment: You haven't specified how the values are delimited in the files or how you want the output to look like. As these may alter the methods you would like to approach this.

Comment: Hi The Duck the data set is tab delimited text file. The output file also should be tab delimited. data=load('Guadiana_50_DTM_xyz_new.txt');

Comment: Hi The Duck the data set is tab delimited text file. The output file also should be tab delimited.  I want to create a text file with x,y,z columns. Model input  is z values according to same order of coordinates. Coordinates are in a different text file. Output values of new z overwrites on input z.txt file) for every 10 years. At the end of the script I want to add a script to combine xy.txt file and z.txt file. Resultant file shold be xyz.txt  Then I load data set as follows: data=load('xyz.txt'); Text files do not have header but in order of the x,y and z.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
%Open and get the relevant data from the two files
fid1 = fopen('xy.txt');
fid2 = fopen('z.txt');
s1 = textscan(fid1,'%s %s','delimiter','\t');
s2 = textscan(fid2,'%s','delimiter','\t');

%close files
fclose(fid1);
fclose(fid2);

%sort data into an easy to use cell array
s=[s1{1,1},s1{1,2},s2{1,1}];

%Create new file and set permission to write
fid = fopen('xyz.txt','w');

%Loop through cell array s and write to file using a tab delimited format spec.
for ind = 1:size(s,1)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\t%s\t%s\n',s{ind,:});
end
fclose(fid); %close file
```

This assumes that xy.txt and z.txt both have the same number of rows

Comment: 258112.5 33766.14 24.9239
258162.5 33766.14 20.7785
258212.5 33766.14 20.4217
258262.5 33766.14 24.5859
258312.5 33766.14 34.7049
258362.5 33766.14 48.2466
258412.5 33766.14 61.3361

Comment: Thank you very much. It joined x,y, and z into a xyz.txt file but I want my xyz.txt file in three different columns to get the contour map. Now text file does not have three separate columns.

Comment: What word processor have you tried for opening the file? If you used Notepad, then it ignores line break symbols. Try opening the text file using Matlab or Word. Or alternatively, use the following to load the file back to matlab:
`fid = fopen('xyz.txt');
s = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s','delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid);`

Comment: Yes xyz.txt opens in matlab with columns. But I could not use the xyz.txt to draw contours & it gave an error (see the my script writen to draw contours at the end of your script). Then I saved xyz.txt file as a ascii file but still it gave an error. 

Then I exported data in xyz.txt into a Excel file and I saved data as a new tab deliminated text file, then I used only the commands to draw contours and it worked without a problem. The problem is I have to use excel to create new text files based on xyz.txt, I want to avoid using excel, I need a complete MATLAB script. see the code below.

Comment: command used to draw contours:                                    load xyz.txt
save Guadiana_50_DTM_xyz_new.txt xyz -ascii

data=load('Guadiana_50_DTM_xyz_new.txt');
x=258000:100:272000; y=18000:100:34000;
[XI,YI]=meshgrid(x,y);
ZI=griddata(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),XI,YI,'v4');
contour(XI,YI,ZI,10)

Comment: Error message: ??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> griddata>gdatav4 at 257
d = xy(:,ones(1,length(xy)));

Error in ==> griddata at 133
    zi = gdatav4(x,y,z,xi,yi);

Error in ==> comb_xyz at 29
ZI=griddata(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),XI,YI,'v4');

Comment: I do not know how to write whole problem at once in this space. Sorry for inconveniance.

Comment: Well, I can suggest you try writing the data to xyz as a csv instead (xyz.csv) using `csvwrite()`, but again, that depends on what you need/require and you specified tab delimited values which is only partially supported (when compared to csv for example). The main problem with importing/exporting data is lack of standards while csv is usually widely supported. The error you are getting there seems to be memory related, try plotting for say 100 lines from xyz.txt rather than the whole thing just to test before moving on